# Avoid the header of box xpath and curl

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, domdocument

Iam writting code to get web data with xpath and curl.

these code get ul li contain and worked.

but I dont want to get header..

I write following code to avoid the header but can't

```
if($row->item(0)->tagName != '<ul class="graybg"><li>مدل خودرو</li>  <li>مشخصات</li><li>قیمت نمایندگی</li><li>قیمت بازار آزاد</li></ul>')
```

full code.

```
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.pedal.ir/price/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;      en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
 $page = curl_exec($ch);


$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($page);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$table_rows = $xpath-   >query('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul '); // target   the row (the browser rendered <tbody>, but actually it really doesnt have one)

 if($table_rows->length <= 0) { // exit if not found
echo 'no table rows found';
exit;
 }

 foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
   $row = $tr->childNodes;
  if($row->item(0)->tagName != '<ul class="graybg"><li>مدل خودرو</li>  <li>مشخصات</li><li>قیمت نمایندگی</li><li>قیمت بازار آزاد</li></ul>') { //  avoid headers
       $data[] = array(
         'moled' =>trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
         'detail' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
            'pricenama' => trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
            'pricebaza' => trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
    );
  }
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($data);;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, since the header has distinct class which identifies it, you could include it inside the checking:

```
foreach($table_rows as $tr) { // foreach row
    $row = $tr->childNodes;

    if($row->item(0)->parentNode->getAttribute('class') !== 'graybg') { //  avoid headers
        $data[] = array(
            'moled' =>trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue),
            'detail' => trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue),
            'pricenama' => trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue),
            'pricebaza' => trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue),
        );
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8D01gZ)

Answer (score 1):

You can add predicate `[not(@class)]` to your xpath to filter out `<ul>` having `class` attribute :

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul[not(@class)]
```

Anyway, absolute path is not reliable as it tends to break due to slight changes to the HTML source. Try to build your xpath base on element's `id` or `class` instead.